# CoreData のデータを SQLite で直接処理する

Tags: swift, ios, coredata

CoreData は実際には SQLite で保存されていると思います。
そうした CoreData の SQLite を アプリ内で SQLite を使って読み込んで、別DBへ移行処理をすることは可能・問題ないでしょうか？
基本 select ですが列を追加したりもするかも知れません。

CoreData で読み込むのがベストだとは思いますが、既存アプリのリプレースで新アプリではCoreDataを使わず別のDBを使う方針なので、できるだけ CoreData のフレームワークを入れたくないと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実体は普通のSQLiteファイルなのでSQLiteを使って直接読み書きすることは可能です。もちろんCore Dataが使うデータ構造を理解している必要があります。また、Core DataがSQLiteをどのように利用しているかは公開されていないので、いつでも変更されうるということに注意が必要です。

まとめると、Core DataのデータをCore Dataを使わずに直接SQLiteで読み書きすることは可能だが、データ構造を壊してしまってCore Dataから読めなくなる恐れがあります。お書きになってるように今後Core Dataを使わないという前提なら問題ないと言えるかもしれません。